# Autofit Div Background Image

Tags: javascript, html, size

I want to set the Div Background image to be fit in a div size. I am trying a lot from google help. but not able to get the solution.

My div property is like below

```
userPic.style.width = "65px";
userPic.style.height = "85px";
userPic.style.position = "absolute";
userPic.style.left = "10px";
userPic.style.top = "10px";
userPic.style.borderRadius = '4em';
```

Now i am setting backround image like below

```
userPic.style.background = "url('"+employee.profilepic+"') no-repeat";
userPic.className = "profilePic";
```

and i set profilepic class like below

```
.profilePic
{
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:auto;
}
```

But background-size:100% is not working properly in chrome and also its not working perfectly. I have div of size 65x85 and my image size is more then this. So how to fit the large or small image in this div?

Comment: did you try with 'cover' or 'contain' property values in background-size?

Comment: i tried but its showing strike in the debug window. that means it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try `background-size: cover;` and see if this gets the desired effect you're after.

Comment: background-size: cover; and content; both are not working. :(

Comment: I got the solution now. You said right. But I should not assign any CSS class name to this. then it will work.